# underline incorrect width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Navigation Links have an animated underline which in screen size <555px shows as being 100% page width when they should only be showing the width of the text. Changing the display to inline-block changes the width but I want the links to display on top of each other not side by side?

http://jsfiddle.net/2tycjc82/

```
/*navigation icon animation*/
var trigger = 'X';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#toggle-menu').click(function () {
trigger = 'X';
$(this).toggleClass('menu-is-active')

});

/* click outside of nav to trigger navigation icon animation*/
$(document).click(function () {


if (trigger == 'X') {
$("#toggle-menu").toggleClass();
trigger = 'ham';
}

});
$("nav").click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
/*----/----navigation icon animation*/

/*toggle menu*/
jQuery("#toggle-menu").click(function () {
jQuery(".nav").slideToggle();
if($("div.header").hasClass("whitenavbar") == false){
$("div.header").addClass("whitenavbar bg navup ");
}else{
$("div.header").removeClass("whitenavbar bg navup");
}

});



/* click outside of nav to close toggle*/
$(document).click(function () {
$(".nav").hide();
});
$("#toggle-menu").click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
/*----/----toggle menu*/

/*navigation background fade in fade out */
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var dist = $('#panel2').offset().top;
    console.log(dist);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > dist) {
        $('.header').addClass('bg');
        $('.header').addClass('navfade');
    }
    else {
        $('.header').removeClass('bg');
    }


});


$('.scroll').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});

/*----/-----navigation background fade in fade out */

});
/*navlist*/
.navigation{
width:100%;
background: #fff;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.navlist {
display: inline-block;
}
.navlist:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 1.5px;
width: 0;
background: transparent;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navlist:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: grey;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
/*----/----navlist*/

/*global styles*/
body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:1.05em;
font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
a {
font-size:1.05em;
font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
background:transparent;
color: grey;
border:none;
letter-spacing:0.15em;
text-transform:uppercase;
transition: color 0.5s ease;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*----/----global styles*/

/*navigation icon*/
 #toggle-menu {
float:right;
display: block;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
padding: 20px;
}
#toggle-menu div {
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
position: relative;
}
.header #toggle-menu span {
display: block;
width: 15px;
height: 3px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s    ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
-moz-transform-origin: center;
transform-origin: center;
}
#toggle-menu span.top {
top: 0px;
}
#toggle-menu span.middle {
top: 6px;
}
#toggle-menu span.bottom {
top: 12px;
}
/*----/----navigation icon*/

/*navigation background transition*/
.bg {
background-color: #fff !important;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.show {
opacity: 1;
}
.navfade {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header .logo { /* Before scroll */
color: white;
}
.bg .logo { /* After scroll */
color: #545454;
}
.navinstagram {
fill: #fff
}
.bg .navinstagram{
fill: #545454;
}

#toggle-menu span{
background: #fff;
}
.bg #toggle-menu span {
background: #545454;
}
/*----/----navigation background transition*/

/*navigation icon animation*/
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top    0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.top, #toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.middle {
top: 6px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.middle {
opacity: 0;
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.bottom {
top: 6px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/*----/----navigation icon animation*/

/*Nav Bar*/
.header {
/*border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);*/
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;
background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
/*background: none;*/
}
.whitenavbar {
background: white;

}
.nav {
display: none;
list-style-type: none;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
left:0;
top: 55px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
cursor: pointer;
color: #545454;
font-size:.8em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
}
.nav li {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
background: #fff;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.seemore {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 20px;
}
#navpromo {
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
padding-bottom: 10px;
background: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
}

#navpromo ul {
margin: 0;
}

.want{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.check{
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) {
    .want{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.check{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}   
}
.instbtn-cont {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn {
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
border: 1px solid grey;
color: grey;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover {
border: none;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-1 {
-webkit-animation: move1 1500ms infinite ease;
animation: move1 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-2 {
-webkit-animation: move2 1500ms infinite ease;
animation: move2 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-3 {
-webkit-animation: move3 1500ms infinite ease;
animation: move3 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-4 {
-webkit-animation: move4 1500ms infinite ease;
animation: move4 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-1 {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
background-color: grey;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-2 {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 1px;
background-color: grey;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-3 {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
background-color: grey;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-4 {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 1px;
background-color: grey;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
0% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}
54% {
height: 0;
bottom: 100%;
}
55% {
height: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
100% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}
}

@keyframes move1 {
0% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}
54% {
height: 0;
bottom: 100%;
}
55% {
height: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
100% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move2 {
0% {
width: 0;
left: 0;
}
50% {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
100% {
width: 0;
left: 100%;
}
}
@keyframes move2 {
0% {
width: 0;
left: 0;
}
50% {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
100% {
width: 0;
left: 100%;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move3 {
0% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}
54% {
height: 0;
top: 100%;
}
55% {
height: 0;
top: 0;
}
100% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}
}
@keyframes move3 {
0% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}
54% {
height: 0;
top: 100%;
}
55% {
height: 0;
top: 0;
}
100% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move4 {
0% {
width: 0;
right: 0;
}
55% {
width: 100%;
right: 0;
}
100% {
width: 0;
right: 100%;
}
}
@keyframes move4 {
0% {
width: 0;
right: 0;
}
55% {
width: 100%;
right: 0;
}
100% {
width: 0;
right: 100%;
}
}
/*----/----Nav Bar*/

/*in*/
.in {
float:left;
display: inline-block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
padding: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
font-size:.8em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
/*----/----in*/

/*logo*/
.logo {
position: absolute;
left: 47%;
display: inline-block;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
padding: 18px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
font-size:.8em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
}
/*----/----logo*/

/****landscape****/
@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) { 
.nav li{
display: block;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.navlist:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 1.5px;
width: 0;
background: transparent;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navlist:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: grey;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
}
/*----/----Landscape*/
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
<a href="" class="in" style="display: inline-block;"> 
<svg class="navinstagram" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 155.2 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 155.2 144;" xml:space="preserve">
<path  d="M42.7,122.7H21.3V54h21.4V122.7z M32,44.6c-6.8,0-12.4-5.6-12.4-12.4c0-6.8,5.5-12.4,12.4-12.4
c6.8,0,12.4,5.5,12.4,12.4C44.4,39,38.9,44.6,32,44.6z M122.7,122.7h-21.3V89.3c0-8-0.1-18.2-11.1-18.2c-11.1,0-12.8,8.7-12.8,17.6
v34H56.1V54h20.5v9.4h0.3c2.8-5.4,9.8-11.1,20.2-11.1c21.6,0,25.6,14.2,25.6,32.7V122.7z"/>
<g>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.9,120c0.7-0.1,1-0.5,1-1.1c0-0.8-0.5-1.1-1.4-1.1H150v4h0.6V120h0.7l0,0l1.1,1.7h0.6L151.9,120
    L151.9,120z M151.3,119.6h-0.7v-1.4h0.9c0.4,0,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.6C152.4,119.5,151.9,119.6,151.3,119.6z"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.3,116c-2.1,0-3.8,1.7-3.8,3.8c0,2.1,1.7,3.8,3.8,3.8c2.1,0,3.8-1.7,3.8-3.8
    C155.2,117.6,153.5,116,151.3,116z M151.3,123.1c-1.8,0-3.3-1.4-3.3-3.3c0-1.9,1.4-3.3,3.3-3.3c1.8,0,3.3,1.4,3.3,3.3
    C154.6,121.7,153.2,123.1,151.3,123.1z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</a>

<a href="" class="logo logocolorchng" style="display: inline-block;">Logo </a>

<a id="toggle-menu">
<div> 
<span class="top"></span>
<span class="middle"></span>
<span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="nav">

<div class="navigation">
<ul>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Home</a></li>            
   <li class="navlist"><a href="#panel2" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Work</a></li>
   <li class="navlist"><a href="#wrapper" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The underline just goes the width of the `li`, which is much wider when all three are stacked on top of each other for smaller screens. Restrict the width to something besides 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the animation to the `a` tags and then use the `.navlist` items to separate each onto its own line:

Take the style attributes off the links and define that in CSS, without the `width` definition.

```
.navlist a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Take the animation off of `.navlist` and put it on the `a` inside it:

```
.navlist a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navlist a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
```

Make the `.navlist` items block so that each link appears on its own line:

```
.navlist {
  display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tycjc82/6/

Answer (score 0):

Add `width` to `ul` and center it, and remove `display: block` from `li`:
http://jsfiddle.net/2tycjc82/7/